# Gradient of a function

Tags: vectors, vector-fields

When I went through the definition of gradient I get to know that it is the change of a function in the three coordinates we have but when we are finding normal to a particular line then we use gradient there but gradient is something that defines how a function is changing in the three coordinates how it can be normal to a given curve? Please explain what is the actual direction of gradient.
Thanks.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I think it's part of physics as well

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You can define gradient for a surface in any number not just three. Its direction is on line of greatest slope. A curve is one dimensional. Normal to a curve only makes sense when you have only one parameter.

Comment: In the case of the curve, what is the function for which you take the gradient? Are you talking about the directional derivative of a function along a curve?

Comment: Yup you got it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First
The gradient of a scalar function $F(x,y,z)$ is a vector that is in the direction in which $F$ undergoes the greatest rate of increase and that has magnitude equal to the rate of increase in that direction. Follow from the fact
$$\left(\frac{dF}{ds} \right)_0= \hat u \cdot (\nabla F)_0$$

Second : $\nabla f(x,y,z)$ where $f(x,y,z)$ is a scalar function ,is normal to the surface $f(x,y,z)=constant$.

both the statement are in different sense,So don't be confused.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you solved my problem